# Using OpenOfficeXML Reference Issue

Tags: c#

I am trying to use `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` to export data, i have red an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692092/A-free-Export-to-Excel-Csharp-class-using-OpenXML) explaining it but after adding the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` reference it can't read the method i try to call like below

```
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(DataSet, "Test.xlsx", Response);
```

it's says it's missing a reference and when i looked about this i found out you need the `windowbase.dll` but it's a windows dll and i can't call it using VS.
Should i be copy the window dll outisde in an "open" folder and call it? or is something i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add this by right clicking on 'references' -> 'add reference' then select the 'Assemblies' menu and 'Framework' sub menu.

Add it from here, somewhere around the bottom of the list.